# How can i load ajax code before js processing?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a review system from a rating via a url.

I would like to use ajax to retrieve the contents of the url to then process it in my js as a number.

But I feel like the ajax happens after my page loads and so my js returns nothing to me.

Do you have an idea to solve my problem please?

Thank you

(I'm a beginner and I tweaked... watch your eyes! ^^ )

```
<body>
     
    <div class="container">
        <div class="medal">
            <pre id="cible"></pre>
            <span class="stars" id="stars" data-rating="" data-num-stars="5" ></span>
            <div class="note"><span id="note"></span><span>/5</span></div>
            <div class="avis"><span id="avis"></span><span> avis clients</span></div>
            <div class="medal_text">Avis vérifiés</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
</body>

ajax/JS

$.ajax({
    method: "GET", // GET ou POST comme tu veut
    url: "content.php", // La page qui va faire le traitement
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        cle: "pre"
    }, // Les donnees a envoyer
    success: function (resultat) {
        $('#cible').html(resultat);
    }
})
 
// LIRE TEXT ET SORTIR TABLEAU DES 2 VALEURS
var myString = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML;
var splits = myString.split(";", 2);
 
console.log(+splits);
console.log(+splits[0]); // affiche "le premier élément"
console.log(+splits[1]);
 
note = splits[1]
 
function roundHalf(note) {
    return Math.round(note * 10) / 10;
}
document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = roundHalf(note);
 
 
avis = splits[0]
document.getElementById("avis").innerHTML = avis;
 
 
// $(element).attr('data-key', 'value');
 
var myData = document.getElementById("stars").setAttribute("data-rating", roundHalf(note));
 
//ES5
$.fn.stars = function () {
    return $(this).each(function () {
        var rating = $(this).data("rating");
        var fullStar = new Array(Math.floor(rating + 1)).join('<i class="fas fa-star"></i>');
        var halfStar = ((rating % 1) !== 0) ? '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>' : '';
        var noStar = new Array(Math.floor($(this).data("numStars") + 1 - rating)).join(
            '<i class="far fa-star"></i>');
        $(this).html(fullStar + halfStar + noStar);
    });
}
 
//ES6
$.fn.stars = function () {
    return $(this).each(function () {
        const rating = $(this).data("rating");
        const numStars = $(this).data("numStars");
        const fullStar = '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>'.repeat(Math.floor(rating));
        const halfStar = (rating % 1 !== 0) ? '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>' : '';
        const noStar = '<i class="far fa-star"></i>'.repeat(Math.floor(numStars - rating));
        $(this).html(`${fullStar}${halfStar}${noStar}`);
    });
}
$(function () {
    $('.stars').stars();
});

php


<?php
$text = file_get_contents("https://cl.avis-verifies.com/fr/cache/2/e/8/2e88d3bd-ea3f-96a4-9db4-70d3c8494879/AWS/2e88d3bd-ea3f-96a4-9db4-70d3c8494879_infosite.txt");
echo json_encode($text);
?>
```

[image: i want 4.68 in "Nan" place]

If i insert directly the content of the url in the html,
`<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">16;4.14</pre>`
and delete the ajax part, the code is working fine.
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJTmH.png)
Why, when i use ajax to fill the  the code bellow doesn't work ?

Comment: Could you explain exactly whats going wrong? Also here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pwzo0v5/1/) I made using your code that does output what I think you want which tells me you need to check the PHP script/path

Comment: Sorry forgot to save the changes on the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pwzo0v5/1/), I've updated it.

Comment: what i want, is to display the numbers of the content of the url in the fields. The result is "Nan" at this time because when i check the console, my console.log are empty or 0. I think my js code is running before ajax send the content.

Comment: It isnt, NAN, you were trying to output the Array as a string and it was throwing an error, use the `myString` var or store it when you get the result from the Ajax call

Comment: i have edit my post with an image to be more understable. Thank you guys. I'll test that this afternoon.

Comment: "But I feel like the ajax happens after my page loads and so my js returns nothing to me." - why not debug that properly? What do you mean by "before js processing"? As AJAX uses JavaScript, there's no way it could run before the other parts are "processed"

Comment: Change you're Ajax call to this with the debug outputs `$.ajax({
    method: "GET", // GET ou POST comme tu veut
    url: "content.php", // La page qui va faire le traitement
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
     cle: "pre"
    }, // Les donnees a envoyer
    success: function (resultat) {
     console.log("Result: " + resultat);
      $('#cible').html(resultat);
    },
    error:function(msg){
     console.log("Error" + msg);
    }
})`

Comment: When i put '<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">16;4.14</pre>' and delete the ajax part, everything is working fine. Why, when i use ajax to fill the <pre> the code bellow doesn't work ?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the work when you have the value, not before.

You have the value in the `success` callback of `$.ajax()`. Every other piece of code in your JS script runs before that.

JS

```
function roundHalf(value) {
    return Math.round(value) / 10;
}
// this section runs before

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "content.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        cle: "pre"
    },
    success: function (resultat) {
        // NOW is the time to do the work
        var splits = resultat.split(";", 2);
        $("#note").text(roundHalf(splits[1]));
        $("#avis").text(splits[0]);
        $("#stars").data('rating', splits[1]).stars();
    }
});

// this section runs before
```

PHP

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("https://cl.avis-verifies.com/fr/cache/2/e/8/2e88d3bd-ea3f-96a4-9db4-70d3c8494879/AWS/2e88d3bd-ea3f-96a4-9db4-70d3c8494879_infosite.txt");
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: It's working perctly. Thanks a lot. My ugly big code seem like crap before you step in ...!